# induction, proof

Tags: induction

3. We define a sequence $a_n$ recursively by the relations: $a_1 = 1$, and $a_{n+1} = \frac{6a_n + 5}{a_n + 2}$ for $n$ positive.  Show that for all $n$ the following two properties hold: 
   (1)  $a_n > 0$; 
   (2) $a_n < 5$.

I was able to do 1) by simply doing $a_n=1$ (given),
then a((1)+1)=(6(1) +5)/(a(1) +2)= 11/3 which is >0..
THen i tried doing induction on n. 
which is $a_{n+2}=\frac{6a_{n+1}+5}{a_{n+1}+2}$..
lots of simplifying and i get to $\frac{41a_n+40}{8a_n+5}$. Plug any #greater than 5  for an and you get a number greater than five.... Not really sure if i'm doing this proof right. just what I've though of as of now. Stuck on (2) $a_n<5$

Comment: Suggest you print out a piece of graph paper and carefully draw the hyperbola $$  y = \frac{6x+5}{x+2} $$  https://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph

Answer (score 0):

For (1) we have that $a_1=1>0$. If we asume that $a_n>0$ for any $n>1$ then $6a_n+5>0$ and $a_n+2>0 \Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{a_n+2}>0$. Therefore $$a_{n+1}=\frac{6a_n+5}{a_n+2}>0.$$ By inductio it follows that $a_n>0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

For two we have that $a_1=1<5$. If we asume that $a_n<5$ for any $n>1$ then $6a_n+5<6\cdot 5+5=35$ and $a_n+2<5+2=7 \Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{a_n+2}>\dfrac{1}{7}$. ¿Can you finish it from here?

Answer (score 0):

If $a_n=5-d_n$ with $0<d_n<5$ then $$a_{n+1}=\frac {6(5-d_n)+5}{(5-d_n)+2}= \frac {35-6d_n}{7-d_n}=\frac {5(7-d_n)-d_n}{7-d_n}=$$ $$=5-\frac {d_n}{7-d_n}$$ which is less than $5$ because $d_n>0$ and $7-d_n>0.$

Notice that $d_n<5$ is from Part (1) and is used to obtain $7-d_n>0$.